# npm command not found in wsl

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, nodejs

I had installed nodejs on windows10 & its path is also set to environment variable. It is working perfectly. As I switched to WSL I found `npm` commands were not working however I could run node.exe from within WSL.
Do I need to install node for wsl separately? please help me I am really a newbie. I might be asking a silly question though.
[screenshot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYLb4.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node.exe` is NodeJS from your Windows environment - that's for Windows, not WSL.

You need to install NodeJS from the NodeJS repositories inside of WSL in order to use `npm` and Node within WSL.  DO NOT rely on the Windows solutions for installing WSL.

[Microsoft has specific documentation on how to do this, provided you're using WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl).  I would suggest following the Microsoft documentation.  (Not copied here because it's a fairly involved process 'cause of making sure you've got WSL2 and such)